# The ActionBar is depriciated, what could be the possible solution?

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("All").setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Not Called").setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Called").setTabListener(this));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    if(tab.getPosition()==0){
    FragmentTop fragmentTop = new FragmentTop();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragmentTop).commit();
    }else if (tab.getPosition()==1){
    FragmentTop2 fragmentTop2 = new FragmentTop2();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragmentTop2).commit();
    }else if (tab.getPosition()==2){
    FragmentTop3 fragmentTop3 = new FragmentTop3();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragmentTop3).commit();
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
   }
}
```

Comment: Use Toolbar instead of ActionBar

Comment: May i know how ? code edit is appriciated. Thanks

Comment: check it out i have share a code in answers

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
if (toolbar != null) {
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
}
tabHost=(FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),android.R.id.tabcontent);
bundle=new Bundle();
// to send data u can send it by binding it with bundle
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"),
        ShowStatusFragment.class,bundle);

tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Tab2"),
        ShowStatusFragment.class,bundle);

tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("Tab3"),
        ShowStatusFragment.class,bundle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should now use [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) which has been brought with [AppCompat v7](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat). (`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'`)

Answer (score 0):

you need to used the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` [AppCompat7](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat)

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
```

add in your Gradle module app